# How to change colours in the RegionPlot Function when three colours are used for three different expressions

Tags: plotting

I am using the RegionPlot function to show contour maps of three expression but I want the white, gray and black colours instead of the default ones. How to change the colours in the RegionPlot Function?

Answer (score 1):

```
RegionPlot[{x^2 < y^3 + 1, y^2 < x^3 + 1, x^2 + y^2 <= 1}, {x, -2, 
  5}, {y, -2, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, White, Black}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> Pink, 2 -> Green, 3 -> Yellow}]
```

[image]